# Adobe native extension Missing Implementation

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flex-mobile, air-native-extension

I'm new in developing **Air Native Extension** and for my learning purpose i'm creating a simple air extension for `Android-ARM` that will add and subtract 2 numbers. I followed this tutorial [turorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt5.html). My directory structure is as below:

```
-android
  -library.swf
  -SampleANE.jar
-extension.xml
-Libr.swc
```

I'm using the following command to make the ane file:

```
adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc Libr.swc -platform Android-ARM -C android
```

But when i run the command to create the ane file, i get "*missing implementation for android-arm*" error. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The command should be this way :

```
adt -package -target ane Output.ane extension.xml -swc Libr.swc -platform Android-ARM -C android .
```

So basically you're just missing a ' .' in the end, from the first one.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

```
adt -package -target ane com.adobe.air.sampleextensions.android.licensing.ane extension.xml -swc AndroidLicensingLib.swc -platform Android-ARM -C .\Android-ARM\.
```

At the end of the line you see ".\Android-ARM." this should actualy be ".\Android-ARM\ .". You need a space before the last period or you will get the "Missing implementation for platform: Android-ARM" error.